# Bootstrap 3 - navbar dropdown menu still visible after closing the dropdown - on viewport < 768px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, navbar, visible, touchscreen

I've been trying to fix the issue with the navbar dropdown menu when using viewport ***smaller than 768px (mobile/touchscreen)***.

When tested on touchscreen, one click is supposed to open the dropdown (this works fine), the second click is supposed to close it (closing of the dropdown works, but on touchscreen it still shows the dropdown menu on the side like it is **ul.dropdown-menu:hover** ).

I am trying to have it hidden after the dropdown toggle is clicked to close, and the cursor is still hovers on the toggle (touchscreen).

Here is the code:

```css
   

ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4474a8;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  background-color: #4474a8
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #4474a8;
  color: #111111!important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

a.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  color: #2f1b09;
}

.dropdown-link {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4474a8;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <img src="#" class="img-responsive center-block" id="logo-top">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <nav class="navbar">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="fa fa-anchor"></span>                   
      </button>

      </div>


      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active" id="active-nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">MENU 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link"><i class="fa fa-ship" aria-hidden="true"></i> SUBMENU 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link"> SUBMENU 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link"> SUBMENU 3<b>&#36;</b></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link"> SUBMENU 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> MENU 5<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Video</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>YouTube</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <!-- @ #banner-->
  <div class="container-fluid" id="banner">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="bannerCol1L">

      </div>
      <!-- / #bannerCol1L -->

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="bannerCol2R">
        <a class="orange pillboxLarge" id="getstarted">BUTTON</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / .row -->
  </div>
  <!-- / .container-fluid  #banner -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, delete the following:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate... believe me I was looking at that exact line for several hours and working around it.  :)

Comment: You're welcome Uros. Sometimes the smallest little things can cause big problems and a lot of frustration. 

Rick Sanchez :)